# How can I fix these artifacts that appear when I set indirect only to my emissive smoke?

Tags: volumetrics, artifacts, emission

**TL;DR: Artifacts appear when smoke with emission set to indirect only.** 
I have this scene which contains a smoke with emission. 
[image: render with smoke] 
 
When I render the scene with indirect only for the smoke these weird squarish artifacts appear. 
[image][image] 
 
I tried increasing the light bounces and decreasing the volumes step rate but it didn't work (or I didn't increase/decrease them enough). 
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Hello and welcom. Can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com